# Open XML populate excel table

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have excel template with empty one-column table. I need to populate it with some string values (this is needed for setting lookups using data validation, but I guess it doesn't really matter)

[image]

I came up to getting Table object and I assume I should use Append method

```
var workBookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
var lookupsSheet = (Sheet)workBookPart.Workbook.Sheets.FirstOrDefault(x => (x is Sheet && ((Sheet)x).Name == "Lookups"));
var worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)workBookPart.GetPartById(lookupsSheet.Id);
var table = worksheetPart.TableDefinitionParts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Table.DisplayName == "ValuesTable")?.Table;
```

Can someone enlighten about the correct way of adding rows to such table. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use the ClosedXML library to set the values of cells in your worksheet. By using ClosedXML, you will be able to populate the cells you want in the following fashion:

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");
// Set the values for the cells
ws.Cell(1, 1).Value = "Value";
ws.Cell(2, 1).Value = 1;        
ws.Cell(3, 1).Value = 2;
ws.Cell(4, 1).Value = 3;
ws.Cell(5, 1).Value = true;
```

Note that you can set the value of a cell to a string, an integer, and a boolean without doing any explicit casting. You can set the value of a cell without doing any explicit casting to other types as well, as it is explained in the following link: [Cell Values.](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Cell%20Values&referringTitle=Documentation)

For more information regarding the ClosedXML library please refer to the [documentation.](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/documentation)

As a side note, I was really eager to use Open XML to manipulate Excel spreadsheets but I found ClosedXML way easier to use.

Comment: Thanks for replay. Yes, this looks much easier for populating cells but main problem was that table was not stretching when cells were populated (and stayed one-row table). However, solution is pretty simple, one just need to update table's reference property  

    `table.Reference = "A1:B6";
    table.AutoFilter.Reference = "A1:B6";`

Comment: @Mykyta Do you mean using Open XML or ClosedXML?

Comment: I achieved this using Open XML directly.